# How to create html table from XML element attributes and XML tags using xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

I'm really new to xslt so I would be very thankful if someone can help me... 
I have a XML like this:

```
        <dummy>
        <element name="O">
            <description/>
        </element>
        <element name="L">
            <description>abstract for L</description>
        </element>
        <element name="Sd">
            <description>Description for Sd</description>
        </element>
        <element name="Dh">
            <description/>
        </element>
        <element name="P">
            <description/>
        </element>
        <element name="S">
            <description>Some description for S</description>
        </element>
        <element name="A">
            <description/>
        </element>
        <L>2010</L>
        <A>58.78</A>
        <O>O</O>
        <Sd>1101</Sd>
        <S>0.00</S>
        <A>368.38</A>
        <L>2009</L>
        <Sd>1103</Sd>
    </dummy>
```

I have to had a final html table like this ( using xslt "1.0"):

```
            <tr>
    <td>
        I have to select only non element tags one by one, and then replace the tag with the 
        description of the same element name (in case that decription does not exists then display only element name). 
    </td>
    <td>
        Value of non element tag
    </td>
    </tr>


4 example ( upper xml) 
    [in something like for-each]:  take  <L> 2010 </L>
```

then search for element name = "L" ( if description exists = true take 
description else "L") and
        display   abstract for L    2010

So the final output 4 given xml should be:

```
    <tr><td> abstract for L  </td> <td> 2010 </td> </tr>
    <tr><td> A  </td> <td> 58.78 </td> </tr>
    <tr><td> O  </td> <td> O </td> </tr>
    <tr><td> Description for Sd </td> <td> 1101 </td> </tr>
    <tr><td> Some description for S  </td> <td> 0.00 </td> </tr>
    <tr><td> A  </td> <td> 368.38 </td> </tr>
    <tr><td> abstract for L  </td> <td> 2009</td> </tr>
    <tr><td> Description for Sd </td> <td> 1103 </td> </tr>
```

The xslt must be written in xslt = "1.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could make use of a **key** here, to look up your **element** nodes by the **name** attribute

```
<xsl:key name="elements" match="element" use="@name" />
```

Firstly, you would need to match all your non-**element** nodes, like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="dummy/*[not(self::element)]" />
```

Then to look up the **description** of the matching **element** you could then use the key set up earlier

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('elements', local-name())"/>
```

You would have two matching templates for the **element** nodes in this case; one for **element** nodes with a **description**, and one for those without.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="elements" match="element" use="@name"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <table>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="dummy/*[not(self::element)]"/>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[not(self::element)]">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elements', local-name())"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="element">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="element[description[node()]]">
      <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following HTML is output:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>abstract for L</td>
      <td>2010</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>58.78</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>O</td>
      <td>O</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Description for Sd</td>
      <td>1101</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Some description for S</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>368.38</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>abstract for L</td>
      <td>2009</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Description for Sd</td>
      <td>1103</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It involves selecting the 'letter' named elements using `name()` in the predicate:

```
<xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:param name='name' select="@name" />
    <td><xsl:value-of select="description" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="//*[name() = $name]" /></td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanx Andrew Shooner 4 your replay, but the result isn't correct. I uppgraded your code with               <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(description) != 0">
         <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>

       </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

Comment: but the given result is ( i'm using xmlspy) :

Comment: <td>O</td>
<td>O</td>
<td>abstract for L</td>
<td>2010</td>
<td>Description for Sd</td>
<td>1101</td>
<td>Dh</td>
<td></td>
<td>P</td>
<td></td>
<td>Some description for S</td>
<td>0.00</td>
<td>A</td>
<td>58.78</td>     . I need to have all the node tags one by one with duplicates, like this

Comment: --------------------------------------------------------------------     <tr><td> abstract for L  </td> <td> 2010 </td> </tr>
    <tr><td> A  </td> <td> 58.78 </td> </tr>
    <tr><td> O  </td> <td> O </td> </tr>
    <tr><td> Description for Sd </td> <td> 1101 </td> </tr>
    <tr><td> Some description for S  </td> <td> 0.00 </td> </tr>
    <tr><td> A  </td> <td> 368.38 </td> </tr>
    <tr><td> abstract for L  </td> <td> 2009</td> </tr>
    <tr><td> Description for Sd </td> <td> 1103 </td> </tr>